# How to fire an event in background?

Tags: ios, objective-c, background, xcode5, uilocalnotification

I am having a method called `-(void)callTheEvent`.

I am writing a code to call the method by using Notifications. But the problem is like until and unless the user tap on notifications the method will not fire. So here I am thinking to implement like without tapping the notification it needs to fire a method. Is there any way to implement like this without server?

Comment: It's not immediately clear what you're trying to achieve.  You want to execute a background task that doesn't require user interaction (i.e. when the app is not in the foreground?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless your application is one of a specific category of applications, then your choices are either to schedule a local notification or a remote notification at the specified time.  You cannot execute *arbitrary* code on a scheduled basis while the application in a background suspended state unless it meets specific criteria.

Example of applications that can run in the background:

- Apps that play audible content to the user while in the background, such as a music player app
- Apps that record audio content while in the background.
- Apps that keep users informed of their location at all times, such as a navigation app
- Apps that support Voice over Internet Protocol (VoIP)
- Apps that need to download and process new content regularly
- Apps that receive regular updates from external accessories

You can refer to the [iOS App Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH1-SW1), skip to the section beginning with the heading *"Implementing Long-Running Background Tasks"*. The criteria noted above are from that reference.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use NSObject's methods

```
- (void)performSelectorInBackground:(SEL)aSelector withObject:(id)arg;
```

or

```
- (void)performSelector:(SEL)aSelector withObject:(id)anArgument afterDelay:(NSTimeInterval)delay;
```